# When Sync my on premise with azure data on premise server gets deleted

Tags: azure, synchronization

I got a Sync between my on-premise server (bidirectional) and my azure db (hub) with the policy hubs win, so when i got new data into my on premise database and try to sync the Sync process deletes records from my on premise database.

i don't have any delete triggers in both tables(on premise or azure)
i'm syncing multiple tables with columns selections
i stop the sync automatically option and the deletes stops, but i did a test manually and continue to delete data on the on premise side and doesn't go to the azure database all the new data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the policy setting when i use the HUB wins the new data that got inserted into my on premise server when the sync runs that data don't got populated to the other database instead it got deleted, so i stop that sync recover the lost data and then recreate the sync but with the policy Client wins and now all data that got into on premise pass to my azure database and vice versa.